# Google chrome extenion

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating Chrome Extension and using Cloud Messaging API to send messages. It is working fine till user is online.  When user is offline, messages send by server gets lost and could not received by the user even if he gets online. Please some one suggest.

Comment: When your device is offline and GCM tries to send it a message, it should be queued on your server and sent out once the device is back online. You'll need to provide more details about your implementation and what actually occurs. Were the messages sent and not received or not sent at all? Is it just a long delay in receiving the message?

Comment: There is no delay of recieving the message. I am sending the message to my chrome extension using gcm. Chrome receives message when its open But does not reciever on close. Also not even when i open chrome again. there is not queuing happening for chrome extension.